# List comprehensions getting wrong output

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
data = [

[
    {'name': 'gan', 'age': 21}, {'name': 'esh', 'age': 22}
],

[
    {'name': 'rahul', 'age': 23}, {'name': 'rohan', 'age': 24}
]

]
u_names = [data['name'] for i in data for j in i if data['age'] > 21]
print(u_names)


line 38, in <module>
    if data['age'] > 21:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I m getting this error whats the reason.

Comment: `data['age']`: data is a list, not a dict, you can't use named indexing. Did you mean `j['age']`?

Comment: I think `u_names = [j['name'] for i in data for j in i if j['age'] > 21] `

Comment: What's not clear about the error? `data` is a list, and you are doing `data["name"]`. Lists can be indexed with numbers not strings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to this:

```
u_names = [j['name'] for i in data for j in i if j['age'] > 21]
```

`data` is a nested list.  `j` is the actual iterated `dict` object inside.

If you rename the objects to more descriptive you'll see the structure:

```
u_names = [
    inner_dict['name']
        for inner_list in data
            for inner_dict in inner_list
                if inner_dict['age'] > 21
    ]
```

Which translates to:

```
for inner_list in data:
    for inner_dict in inner_list:
        if inner_dict['age'] > 21:
            return inner_dict['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
u_names = [j['name'] 
for i in data:
    for j in i:
         if j['age'] > 21:
             print(u_names)
```

By accessing `data['name']`, you're trying to access a property `name` on your original data array, not the sub-array assigned to `i` in your comprehension.

Comment: `data['name']` is not accessing a property of the `list`.  It's trying to slice the `list` with a `str` value.